# New or existing App service plan in Azure deployment

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

When I publish an api to azure from visual studio I see an existing app-service plan and also an option to create a new plan. The api I am going deploy will be used by the web application which was deployed using the existing service. 
I have the following questions:

1. If I use the existing plan what would happen to the sites which are
   already deployed using that plan?
2. Should I create new or use
   existing?
3. Cost-wise which is the best option?

Answer (score 2):

By using the same service plan to host the web app and the api, nothing will happen to the existing website besides you won't have any extra cost. The web apps will share the same resources.

If you create a new service plan for you api, you will have extra cost depending on the pricing tier you need.

The choice can depend on your scaling needs. If you need to define differents scaling plan for the api and the web app, it's a good idea to use two services plan, if not an unique service plan can be used.